# Speed limits during navigation

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am building a navigation app using the **Mapbox**.
I want to obtain some information like **speed limits during navigation**.
Could anyone please help me?

sample code:-

```
NavigationLauncherOptions options = NavigationLauncherOptions.builder()
        .directionsRoute(currentRoute)
        .shouldSimulateRoute(false)
        .build();
NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(getActivity(), options);
```

Answer (score 1):

As no one posted an actual "copy-paste" answer yet, and I have struggled a lot to achieve working code, I will post my answer here.

First of all you need to add `maxspeed` annotation to your request. You can do it like this:

```
 final RouteOptions.Builder builder = RouteOptions
    .builder()
    .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
    // more optionst
    .overview(OVERVIEW_FULL) // required
    .annotationsList(Arrays.asList(DirectionsCriteria.ANNOTATION_MAXSPEED)); // obviously required
```

And then you need to add `RouteProgressObserver` to your `NavigationViewOptions`
In `RouteProgressObserver` you now should be able to get max speed list (speed between each route coordinate) with such code:

```
@Override
public void onRouteProgressChanged(@NotNull RouteProgress routeProgress) {
    List<MaxSpeed> maxspeed = routeProgress
        .getCurrentLegProgress()
        .getRouteLeg()
        .annotation()
        .maxspeed();
}
```

Hope it will help somebody)

Comment: after long time this worked!!  `.annotationsList(Arrays.asList(DirectionsCriteria.ANNOTATION_MAXSPEED)); // obviously required `

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/directions/#travel-times it appears you could access speed limits via the https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:maxspeed from openstreetmap. This is what Mapbox is using internally for its router.

Comment: it is already done brother before 3 month @moritz thanks for reply

Comment: @KaushPar Can you please tell me or post answer how you did it?